# How to use DrawingContext.DrawText to cut word

Tags: c#, wpf

In FormattedText, there are three options for trimming. 
For example, I want to rendering 'A Test'
CharacterEllipsis will show 'A T...'
None will show 'A'
WordEllipsis will show 'A...'
Is there any way to show the result 'A T'? I mean without ellipsis.

Comment: Do you mean don't show the ellipsis (...)? That may confuse user.

Comment: Yep. I do not want the ellipsis.